# Communication between different parts of modules / bundles of the application for maximum decoupling?

Tags: php, api, symfony, bundle

I'm looking into building my application as flexible, decoupled as possible.

I'll be split the application into different bundles which handles clear responsibilities.

Now to the main concern of mine, how do I actually make two or more bundles share information in a decoupled way?

I've been looking into different paradigms like headless CMS, microservices architecture etc that has inspired me.

Let's say I have a UserBundle which handles the registration and login of users. Then I have another bundle, DashboardBundle. DashboardBundle's responsibility is not to handle the users, but it do need to display a "Hello John Doe" message at the top of the menu bar.

Solutions I've thought so far:

1. One way I though about solving this would be that each bundle could actually provide it's own API. Meaning that the dashboard bundle would simply make a API call to the UserBundles API, asking for the currently logged user.
2. UserBundle would provide a UserManager service or something similar, that would be the layer between UserBundle and any other Bundle / Code needing to talk to the UserBundle.

*The two first solutions would still couple together to bundles, BUT they could be developed quite independent, even though DashboardBundle is obviously dependent on UserBundle.*

Is this really stupid if I want to achieve decouple, or is this actually a valid approach forward? If these are actually not crazy ideas, do anyone have names of concepts that this is called so I could read further into this idea?

Answer (score 0):

you find some answer [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/creating-the-project.html#application-bundles) and used design pattern concepts is a good solution for decoupeling/coupeling and other problems. But it's nice to not exaggerate and too complicate your application.

Comment: Thanks! I've read that part of the practice that bundles should be abled to be used "as is", but I do not agree with that. I'm coming from the world of Magento, where modules are first-class citizens, but they are allowed to be dependent on other modules. I want to split my application down in chunks that is more focused, but still being part of a large application.

Comment: the concept of bundles ins not the same of Magnto modules.Everyone has their best practises.

Comment: Yes, I'm fully aware of that, since that's what the documentation is saying. But I do not have to agree with that, and follow that practice for my own application. But this is outside the concern of the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in the modular system must be independent. Symfony used the EventDispatcher for this job. If you create an event in Javascript, then you call this event in a different module (Bundle). With Eventdispatcher you can build a structure like WordPress hook system. You can use KnpMenuBundle for menus. With EventDispatcher, you can add menus from different bundle.

Comment: But I get that, from when I from one Bundle wants to inject stuff into another. But my example above is different, I want from one Bundle retrieve information from another Bundle. Not injecting information.

Comment: is the same case when used third party bundles (vendor), you have access to services, parameters, configuration ect

Comment: This depends on the type of information you want. With annotation you can read the header information, you can create API.

Comment: Hoping I do not sound completely out of my mind here but, I do not follow what you mean. Could you give an example. Let's take the one above, where I have for example a front page, which has should have a small box saying "Hello Username!". Since the user is provided by the UserBundle, how would the PageBundle, or DashboardBundle get access to that user? Would that be through a service then? Just a plain old service called "User" or would it make sense to call it "UserManager" or something similar? Is this what you mean?

Comment: It is related to your need and cases, if you need current connected user symfony provide methods to use in controller or twig. If just a user you musr provide reusable services or API to access informations outside bundle developped in your UserBundle for example.

Comment: With Doctrine, you can access other packaged entity information. Symfony already offers tools for active user information. You create a core package and all visual systems work through this package. Add all core features required by the system (DashboardBundle). Then you integrate the menus with EventDispatcher. Show the file in your kernel package (base.html.twig) as the visual base file of your new package (DashboardBundle). In this way you can create pages like "Hello Username". I use the same kind of system on my own project and basically there are two mandatory packages (User&AdminBundle)

Comment: @RamazanApaydin I find your answer quite interesting. Do you perhaps have any open source example of your approach? Or any code based examples?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you are mixing concepts. The should be reusable parts of your app (like user manager, connection to external services and so on that should be bundles. Then once they are bundles you decide to load them as vendor o as bundles. But the core part of your app must be in AppBundle, because that part must be the most specific for your app and for that reason the less reusable code.

So what I would do is to make the most general parts of your app bundles (or reuse existing bundles) and then a single AppBundle with the app specific code.

The general parts are injected in your AppBundle as services, or inheritance (i.e. for entity definition) and your specific part of code is the one in charge of knowing how to speak with the vendors or another bundles.